# Is short code mandatory in a code golf submission?

Tags: discussion

If there is a code golf competition are you allowed to submit a submission that is clearly not going to win? I.E thousands of bytes? I know they do say that solutions must be serious competing entries, but for the sake of a complete answer as well as personal interest are such answers permitted. I feel like these esolangs are really killing languages like Java and Python. Are such answers permitted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All answers must be serious contenders for the winning criteria in use. For code golf, that means you should make your code as short as you can.

What this means:

- Don't leave any superfluous whitespace in your code.
- Don't make variable names longer than they have to be.
- Don't implement features the challenge doesn't require (prompts, input checks, etc.).
- Don't get hung up on best practices or style guides. Code golf is about *short* code, not *good* code.

You can still use any language you like, no matter how verbose. Just try to make the answer *in that language* as short as you can. Comparing scores of different languages is rather meaningless anyway, even when it comes to "real" languages. J almost always beats Perl, which almost always beats Python, which almost always beats Java, which almost always beats Rust...

Note that I said *as short as **you** can*. Even if somebody posts a shorter solution, you shouldn't feel discouraged.

Summing up, just have fun golfing and don't worry about that rule.

Comment: "don't worry about that rule" seems antithetical to the points made in this answer, with respect to the question ("do all submissions have to be golfed?").

Comment: My point is, as long as one is actually *golfing* his code, he'll satisfy the requirement.

Comment: I absolutely agree with this answer, but I will say occasionally it's hard to tell if a new user is unaware that it needs to be golfed or just inexperienced at golfing. For example, if a new user posts a python answer with 4 spaces for indentation, are they not even trying, or bad at golfing? This problem becomes worse as I get better at golfing, and pick up the tips and tricks of it.